# extending background horizontally outside div

Tags: html, css

I have some css:

```
.note {
  background: red;
}

.note > div {
  max-width: 780px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.note > div:before {
  content: '⚠';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

And a corresponding html like:

```
<div class='note'><div>Foobar</div></div>
```

This creates a red line across the screen, but the content will be only in the center area. It works well so far. But I want the whole content to be in a 800px width area, so I add a container:

```
#container {
  max-width: 790px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And some html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <div class="note"><div>foo</div></div>
  <p>Foobar</p>
</div>
```

Of course, note won't work here (the red line doesn't extend beyond the green container). I've been trying to come up with something, but I couldn't.  I can't just close the container, place my note, and open another because border-radius and (and also box shadow, but I left it out from the example) would break then. Using a negative margin on `.note` also doesn't work, because it adds horizontal scrollbars. I could make `.note` `position: absolute;`, but then my note would overlap whatever comes after it.

Any ideas how could I solve it?

**Update**: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTvPX/). The second version is what I actually want, except that it creates a vertical scrollbar. The third is like Robert's solution, and the only problem is that it takes the div out of flow, and I'd like to avoid hacks like adding a margin-top to the following element because I don't know the length of the note in advance.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Definitely need a Fiddle for this and be sure to not leave anything out as you mentioned you did in your last paragraph :)

Comment: So if I get it correctly, you want the red line inside your container to span the viewport width (or just the #container width?) without hiding the box-shadow and preserving the border-radius?

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle. I'd like the div to be viewport width, like in the third example, except that it hides part of the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
.note {
  background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ySVZb/

Note that I changed some widths so it's easier to see in the jsfiddle screen, but the size is irrelevant.  Also note that because I've taken the note div outside the normal flow, you will need to add an appropriate margin to anything that follows or it will fall behind the note div.  Some generic like `.note + * {margin-top: 2em}` will work in some cases, but it will override any margin top already on that element, in those cases you'll need a more specific fix like `.note + p {margin-top: 3em;}` jsfiddle showing that here: http://jsfiddle.net/ySVZb/1/